# Do Engle-Granger residuals need to be normally distributed?

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Do EngleGranger residuals need to be normally distributed?

Comment: Does the Engle-Granger paper say anything about this? Have you checked it? (It will probably stay a rhetorical question before the OP gets enough points to comment.)

Answer (score 1):

The Engle and Granger test for cointegration is basically an ADF test in the estimated error of the long run equation, say $\hat{u}$. The ADF test is looking for stationarity of this process (or trend-stationary). **It does not require normality**, as there are many non-normal processes which are stationary (see [here](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~dbackus/BCZ/discrete_time/Sim_nonnormal_JF_94.pdf) or [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/481/does-the-autocorrelation-function-completely-describe-a-stochastic-process/488#488)).

For instance, [this paper](https://www.fdic.gov/bank/analytical/cfr/2009/wp2009/CFRWP_2009_09_Kyungso.pdf) compares the power of different unit root tests (including ADF) for a whole range of distribution of the variable in question. Distributions include normal and non-normal like Chi-squared, Beta, and Laplace (double exponential in their terminology). Their interest is to propose more powerful unit root tests, but an aside conclusion is that, even under non-normality, the ADF test performs "well" (their proposed tests perform better though).

Having this in mind, the next question is: does the error in a cointegrated, long run equation has to be normal? This is akin to the question of whether errors in a regression have to be normal. There are tons of related posts in CV about this. The short answer seems to be: hopefully yes, but might not be. Examples [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130775/why-do-we-care-so-much-about-normally-distributed-error-terms-and-homoskedastic), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100214/assumptions-of-linear-models-and-what-to-do-if-the-residuals-are-not-normally-di), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/regression-when-the-ols-residuals-are-not-normally-distributed), and more generally, [here](http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=non-normal+errors+regression).

(Richard Hardy's summary of this normality issue in the comments is certainly more precise on this than my summary. Basically, if you have a small sample, you want normality, so that standard tests have the theoretical distribution the should have (so, tests are valid). If you have a large sample, the Central Limit theorem will do that job for you.)

Comment: Three points: (1) minor quibble: *predicted error*? I would say *residual (=estimated error)*; (2) the existence of nonnormal yet stationary processes cannot by itself imply anything about the assumptions of the ADF test, so the first paragraph suggests a misleading connection; (3) the short answer is, normality of errors is required only for the validity of small sample $t$ and $F$ tests (while consistency, asymptotic normality, Gauss-Markov theorem does not rely on normality).

Comment: Thanks. Added the comments you mention. Let me know if I was right in (3). Feel free to edit if not.

Comment: That's better, although the first paragraph is unchanged and still suggests a relation between the assumptions of ADF test and general requirements for stationary processes.

Comment: Mmm, what I am saying is that ADF tests for stationarity and that normality is not necessary, as there are many stationary but non-normal processes. The point of the new second paragraph was to show an example that indeed the ADF test remains valid even with non-normal but stationary processes, confirming the first paragraph claim.

Comment: The problem is that ADF is not a *general* test for *any type* of stationarity, and therefore it may or may not have specific assumptions beyond what is required for stationarity in general -- just to stress the logic of the argument. Now we know that ADF test does not require normality -- but it is *not because* stationarity does not require normality, but rather because such is the construction/design of the ADF test.

Comment: I see. There can be tests for stationarity which require normality, and others that do not. I was assuming that all of them do not, even if we know that the ADF does not.

Comment: Came here accidentally and noticed again that the argument *It does not require normality, as there are many non-normal processes which are stationary* is not logically sound as pointed out above...